# implementation of object level raw permissions inside microservice architecture

Tags: authorization, microservices, acl

I have a bunch of microservices running. I have an api gateway that connect consumers to all these services. Now on some services I need to give permission to certain users ( users are stored in separate Users Service ). For example if I have a blog service I need to give `blog 1`, `blog 2` and `blog 3` view permissions only to `user 1` and not to `user 2` ( the scenario is `acl` rather than RBAC or ABAC i think, correct me if i am worng ). Now how should i implement the permission system.

For example If store the permission on each entity object inside each microservice as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837207/entity-level-access-restriction-in-the-microservice-architecture-based-on-user-o) then each of my service has to know about users also to grant them permissions. this scenario will compel me to synchronize the users data across all microservices ( on users delete update ... ).

Another Solution is to create a separate generic authorization service to manage all services permissions. but this solution will require me to save each microservice schema ( and have to synchronize that schema on change )

Or there is any other solution. please help. how to implement ACL (authorization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to introduce userID into the downstream path from the gateway. So the path

```
GET /blogs/{blogId}
```

is exposed on the gateway, but this becomes

```
GET /blogs/{userId}/{blogId}
```

on the blogs microservice. The gateway handles the user's bearer token and injects the user's ID into the downstrteam call. The blogs microservice would then return the blog for a "valid" path, or a 404 if the path was not valid.

This is illustrated here:

[image]

> the backend service maintains which users have access to which blogs?

The blog microservice stores and manages blogs. A blog can have an access list associated with it. That list may contain only the user who is the blog owner, or more than one user. The point is that the ACL is not centralised, but distributed with each blog's data containing it.

> if a user is deleted

Then you have two choices. If the user is deleted you publish a *UserDeleted* event, to which the blogs service is subscribed. Then you can manage all the blogs which have the user in their ACL and remove them. Or, you can do nothing. I would personally choose the latter; one of the features of having a microservice architecture is that some data will not be consistent. If you require absolute consistency then you can have a "caretaker" process which removes deleted users out of blog ACLs. Or don't use microservices.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. in this case the backend service is maintaining the permissions between the blog and the users. i.e the backend service maintains which users have access to which blogs? . and if this is the case how to synchronize the users data ( e.g if a user is deleted) and that information about blog and deleted user is still there